# .net core 2.1 razor page view does not update correctly when remove object from collection in object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

Below is my get handler in pageModel

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OnGet(int? Id)
{
    if (Id == null || Id == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    MyContractPermission = _context.ContractPermission.Where(x => x.Id == Id).Include(c => c.BudgetAssignYears)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears == null || MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears.Count == 0)
    {
        MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears = new List<BudgetAssignYear>();
    }

    YearList = new SelectList(SamfaEnums.Years);

    return Page();
}
```

and this is Razor View  :

```
<form method="post">
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears.Count; i++)
{
    var j = i + 1;
    <tr class="d-flex" budgetRow>
        <td class="col-1">
            <span class="persian-number">@j</span>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears[i].ContractPermissionId" />                                                        
        </td>
        <td class="col-2">                            
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears[i].Year, SamfaEnums.Years.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s, Value = s, Selected = s == "1397" ? true : false }), new { @class = "form-control", @yearSelect = "" })
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears[i].Year"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="col-2">
            <select asp-for="MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears[i].BudgetType" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<BudgetType>()">
                <option selected="selected" value="">choose one </option>
            </select>
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears[i].BudgetType"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="col-2">                            
        </td>                                               
        <td class="col-2">                            
        </td>
        <td class="col-2 in-center">
            <input type="submit" value="delete" class="icon-red" asp-route-index="@i"
                   asp-page-handler="Delete"
                   onclick="return confirm('do you sure?');" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</form>
```

and finally Delete handler in my page model is like this :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int index)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }            
    MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears
        .Remove(MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears[index]);            
    YearList = new SelectList(SamfaEnums.Years);
    return Page();
}
```

when I clicked on delete submit button **Delete** Handler in page model has been called and object in **BudgetAssignYears** property deleted Matched with submitted **index**, but after comeback from handler in view just remove last object.
I delete first object but after post, remove last object.
In debug mode every thing is ok and object in index removed, but in view just remove last item.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue as you. Adding modelstate.clear() before removing the row fixed it for me.
Try

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int index)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
        return Page();
   }
   ModelState.Clear();
   MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears
       .Remove(MyContractPermission.BudgetAssignYears[index]);            
   YearList = new SelectList(SamfaEnums.Years);
   return Page();
}
```

> "If you are getting your Model from a form and you want to manipulate the data that came from the client form and write it back to a view, you need to call ModelState.Clear() to clean the ModelState values." https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/modelstate-clear-is-required-to-display-back-your-model-object